# AWS RDS Periodic Writes

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS postgres instance (v15) that doesn't see much usage. However, every three hours at around the half hour mark, I get a flurry of writes (see screenshot, below). At first, I thought this might be some auto-vacuuming but I checked with `select relname,last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_user_tables;` and they didn't seem to line up.

What's going on?

[image]

EDIT - as suggested in the comments by @Tim, I turned on logging. Unfortunately, there's just nothing happening around the times I see increased spikes. There are some buffer writes but those are happening at other times, too.

18:35 UTC

- 2023-11-15 18:29:39 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.121 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=67050 kB
- 2023-11-15 18:29:42 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:30:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:32:42 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:33:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:34:39 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 18:34:39 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.122 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=66898 kB
- 2023-11-15 18:35:42 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:36:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:38:42 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:39:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 18:39:39 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 18:39:39 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 2 recycled; write=0.106 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.125 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=131071 kB, estimate=131071 kB

12:35 UTC

- 2023-11-15 12:34:25 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 7 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.508 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.531 s; sync files=6, longest=0.005 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65541 kB, estimate=65541 kB
- 2023-11-15 12:34:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 12:36:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 12:37:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 12:39:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 12:39:26 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 12:39:26 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 5 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.306 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.323 s; sync files=5, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=65532 kB, estimate=65540 kB

09:35 UTC

- 2023-11-15 09:24:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.121 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
- 2023-11-15 09:25:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:27:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:28:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:29:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 09:29:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.121 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
- 2023-11-15 09:30:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:31:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:33:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:34:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 09:34:23 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.107 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.125 s; sync files=3, longest=0.004 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
- 2023-11-15 09:34:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:36:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:37:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:39:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 09:39:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 09:39:22 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.124 s; sync files=3, longest=0.004 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB

06:35 UTC

- 2023-11-15 06:29:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 06:29:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.004 s, total=0.120 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65549 kB
- 2023-11-15 06:30:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:31:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:33:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:34:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 06:34:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.122 s; sync files=3, longest=0.004 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65547 kB
- 2023-11-15 06:34:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:36:19 UTC:10.102.102.132(50721):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[14275]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:37:28 UTC:10.102.103.139(7717):qd_dev_backend@qd_dev_backend:[19325]:LOG: statement:
- 2023-11-15 06:39:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
- 2023-11-15 06:39:17 UTC::@:[374]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.105 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.122 s; sync files=3, longest=0.003 s, average=0.002 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65546 kB

Comment: Can you turn on statement logging?

Comment: @Tim thanks, good thought. Just did and will see what happens..